# How can I add a custom context menu to all extensions of a particular type (e.g. all video files)

Tags: windows-10, registry, file-type

#### Background/Problem

I have added custom context menus to a number of filetypes individually...

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
  VIDEO_FILETYPE_1 (.MP4)
    SHELL
      CUSTOM_MENU
        COMMAND
  VIDEO_FILETYPE_2 (.MKV)
    SHELL
      CUSTOM_MENU
        COMMAND
```

However, this only applies specifically to the filetypes configured...
✅ .MP4 files
✅ .M4V files
❌ .MOV files

I could keep customising more and more filetypes in the registry, however this is already starting to get a bit tedious (have tweaked 30+ types so far) and time-consuming to update (for example: changing an icon means running 30+ .reg scripts).

Conversely, I don't really want to extend the * filetype as there is no point asking if I want to .reg file with Avidemux for example.

---

#### Solution needed

Is there a way I can add (attach) a custom context menu to *ALL* filetypes of a particular type (e.g. video)...

For example...

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
  VIDEO
    SHELL
      CUSTOM_MENU
        COMMAND
```

This then adds the menu to all filetypes where PerceivedType=Video...
✅ .MP4 files
✅ .M4V files
✅ .MOV files

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can register supplemental verbs based on the perceived type under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\video\shell`. This works on Windows XP and later and is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/app-registration#registering-a-perceived-type).

[image: Regedit and shell menu]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion... Unfortunately I've tried this before (and re-tried it again now just to be sure), however it does not seem to work.

I added two new verbs under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT > SystemFileAssociations > video > shell`... [1] `OpenVLC > command` [2] `Edit > command` (just to try a canonical verb)

However either neither were available for any video file. 

Comment: It does work but not always 100%. I can't explain why but the file types Windows knows about seem to work better than other types. Anyway, make sure you register the command correctly and use Process Monitor to watch Explorer access the registry.

Comment: Thanks, but am not really sure how to use Process Monitor to help me in this situation though am afraid... I have used it **very** briefly in the past (to no avail) -- have re-downloaded it again now, opened it, filtered the 1,200,000 lines of detail by `HKCR\SystemFileAssociations\video` which returned ~400 lines of info, however they do not mean much to me sadly ...  E.g. `Query: HandleTags  HandleTags: 0x0` -- is this good (correct), bad (indicative of an error), irrelevant?... I dunno ‍♂️ lol

Comment: Just filter by `SystemFileAssociations\video` and look at RegOpenKey and RegQueryValue operations.

Comment: That's what I did above, however like I say I am unsure what to do next... Used ProcessMon again today, setup filter, right clicked on .mp4 file and it generated 110 lines... #1 `HKCU\SFA\video - Desired Access: Read` ❌ FAILED (fine as used HKLM)... #2 `HKCR\SFA\video - Desired Access: Read` ✅ SUCCESS... #3 `HKCR\SFA\video - Query: Name` ✅ SUCCESS... #4 `HKCR\SFA\video - Query: HandleTags, HandleTags: 0x0` ✅ SUCCESS.... etc, etc... However I can't tell if these calls are expected or show an error... None of the 110 lines refer (there are no `RegQuery` calls) to the 2 new verbs I added 

Comment: PS - I would be happy to upload a screenshot / export from ProcessMonitor, however I don't think I can (I can't see any option to) attach a file as part of a comment... PS - Apologies, I have been reading posts on stackoverflow.com for years, however am very new as a poster (this is my first question, lol)

Comment: PPS -- I was re-reading [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/app-registration#registering-a-perceived-type) / trying to think how to possibly get this working... 1️⃣ Do you know if PerceivedTypes are protected keywords / fixed enum list? -- i.e. to try and narrow-down the issue, could I set `[.mp4] PerceivedType=video2` and try creating verbs under `[HKLM\SFA\video2]`, or would this not work?... 2️⃣ Also (if I did this), I assume types generally / for things like searching, are not affected by PerceivedType (and it's generally `[KindMap]` instead that control this)?

Comment: I believe the list is fixed and Windows probably already knows mp4 (PERCEIVEDFLAG_HARDCODED), you cannot change it. On my machine .mp4 does not work but the menu item is there for .avi!

Comment: You're right!... Just tried it too, annoyingly though I could only get it to work for .avi -- .mp4 .m4v .mov .mkv all failed to show the menu ... Can you provide any more info about the `PERCEIVEDFLAG_HARDCODED` you mentioned, please (I have not seen / heard of it before)... Is it a reg value?... Is there no way to change it at all?

Comment: It is a flag returned by the AssocGetPerceivedType function, you can read about it on MSDN.